# function onTouch() for LinearLayout doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have file FirstLevel where user goes from the main file(mainActivity). I need to add LinearLayouts to the screen in FirstLevel (these LinearLayouts contain two TextViews and are realised in separate XML-file), when user touches the screen. But, actually, nothing happens, I don't see any added LinearLayouts.

```java
public class First_level extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {
    ImageButton firstButton;
    //boolean flag = true;
    String[] replics  = {...}; //filled massives
    String[] who = {...};
    int i = 0;
    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first_level);
        LinearLayout gameWindow = findViewById(R.id.mesWin);
        gameWindow.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    void npcsay(String text, String hero)
    {
        LinearLayout gameWindow = findViewById(R.id.mesWin);
        LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.message, gameWindow, false);
        TextView username = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        username.setText(hero);
        TextView ttxt = view.findViewById(R.id.point);
        ttxt.setText(text);
        gameWindow.addView(view, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }


    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            npcsay(replics[i], who[i]);
            i++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

First_level.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/gameWindow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/fillback"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mesWin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</ScrollView>
```

message.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/grey_background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/neucha"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="User"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/point"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/neucha"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="hi"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="21sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

That is how first_level XML looks like.

[image: That is how first_level XML looks like.]

Comment: hi, can you post first_level.xml file, so i can debug your problem.

Comment: hi, @Daniel.Wang, did it!

Comment: Updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: For the future: Please never edit a question in a way that invalidates existing answers. Ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your problem.
You set onTouchListener to LinearLayout(R.id.mesWin).
But size of LinearLayout is 0. (Because you set it's size to **wrap_content**).
So you can fix it by two methods.

**First method:**
You can change TouchListener to gameWindow.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.first_level);
    View gameWindow = findViewById(R.id.gameWindow);
    gameWindow.setOnTouchListener(this);
}
```

**Second method:**

You can change height of LinearLayout(mesWin).
So you need to add fillViewport="true" option to ScrollView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/gameWindow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/fillback"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mesWin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is commonly good pratice to use "ViewGroup.addView(child, LayoutParams)" instead of just "addView()" especially when XML Layout has main ViewGroup set as "*width/height: match_parent*". Infact default LayoutParams assigned to any inflated View (using "addView(child)" is "*wrap_content*" for both Widht and Height and in this way the inflated view cannot be measured well and its dimensions will be [0,0].

Please check your XML Layout file: it should be measurable from its own (in other words it should not depends of Parent width/height). If it should depends of Parent's ViewGroup then you cannot use "*addView(child)*" but you need

- addView(child, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(..., ...));

according to your View.

If you're not sure about it please post your XML "R.layout.message" file.

Comment: thanks a lot! I edited my file as You said, but it still doesn't work, and I believe that the problem is bond with function onTouch(), because when i just add linearLayouts to the main linearLayout (without ontouch), everything works

Comment: Nope, onTouch() cannot ruins anything because runs in the Main/UiThread like other Activity methods. I think in the "other place" it's working mostly by lucky than because it's the right way. Programming is something solid/stable and cannot work "sometimes" or "only if I put code here".....

Comment: fine @emandt, I understood! could You please check the XML "message" file that I posted? it seems that I edited the file not correctly

Comment: (1) "fill_parent" is deprecated/old attribute value that is not more used from years. Replace it with "match_parent". (2) do you see ScrollView "fillblack" background in the right place and with right width/hight? (post a picture of the resulting View, if you can)

Comment: (1) fixed! (2) I believe everything is okay, posted the picture

Comment: @DaniLauri So my answer (1) fixes the issue but you accepted another anwser as the Right one?.......

Comment: Ah, sorry, probably I chose not right word, I meant that I did everything as You said, but actually it didn't help...